# Using where in LINQ select new statement for specific columns

Tags: c#, linq

I'm working on a class assignment and got a bit lost in LINQ.

I have 3 tables, 'oltandok' contains the data of persons, 'preferenciak' contains the preferred vaccine of that person with 3 columns:

- an FK for table oltandok
- a number indicating the order of preferences (1 is highest, 6 is lowest preferred)
- an FK for another table containing the data on the vaccines called 'vakcinak'

I would like to display the data in a DataGridView the following way:
Personal data and the preferred vaccines in different columns:

- Pref1 - Name of the vaccine where pref == 1
- Pref2 - Name of the vaccine where pref == 2
- etc.

This is where I am with my code, but I'm not sure how to select the preferences properly.

```
manu_rogz.DataSource = ( from x in context.oltandok
                         join y in context.preferencia on x.TAJ equals y.oltandok_FK
                         select new
                         {
                             TAJ = x.TAJ,
                             Nev = x.nev,
                             Szuletesnap = x.birthdate,
                             Pref1 = ???
                             Pref2 = ???
                         }
                       ).ToList();
```

Comment: I've no time to write an answer (sorry), but a search for "linq transpose rows to columns" should bring some helpful results.

Comment: Can you post vakcinak class, and would be nice if you post 2 another classes too

Answer (score 1):

Because the `preferenciak` table contains multiple rows per person, you will need to perform some grouping.

Here is some **very rough** code which illustrates one way to do that.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var persons = new List<Person> { new Person { ID = 11, PersonName = "Alice" }, new Person { ID = 22, PersonName = "Bob" } };
        var vaccines = new List<Vaccine> { new Vaccine(){ ID = 111, VaccineName= "Pfizer" }, new Vaccine(){ ID = 222, VaccineName = "Moderna" } };
        var preferences = new List<VaccPref>
                              {
                                  new VaccPref() { Person_FK = 11, Preference = 1, Vaccine_FK = 111 },
                                  new VaccPref() { Person_FK = 11, Preference = 2, Vaccine_FK = 222 },
                                  new VaccPref() { Person_FK = 22, Preference = 1, Vaccine_FK = 222 },
                                  new VaccPref() { Person_FK = 22, Preference = 2, Vaccine_FK = 111 }
                              };

        var prefsWithVaccNames = preferences.Join(vaccines, p => p.Vaccine_FK, v => v.ID, (pref, vaccine) => new Tuple<VaccPref, string>(pref, vaccine.VaccineName));

        var groupedPrefs = prefsWithVaccNames.GroupBy(p => p.Item1.Person_FK);

        var personPrefs = new List<PersonPrefs>();
        foreach (var group in groupedPrefs)
        {
            personPrefs.Add(
                new PersonPrefs()
                    {
                        Person_FK = group.Key,
                        Pref1 = group.Single(v => v.Item1.Preference == 1).Item2,
                        Pref2 = group.Single(v => v.Item1.Preference == 2).Item2,
                    });
        }

        var personPrefsWithPersonNames =
            personPrefs.Join(
                persons,
                pp => pp.Person_FK,
                p => p.ID,
                (pp, p) => new NamedPersonPrefs() { Name = p.PersonName, Pref1 = pp.Pref1, Pref2 = pp.Pref2 }).ToArray();

    }
}

class Person
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string PersonName { get; set; }
}

class VaccPref
{
    public int Person_FK { get; set; }
    public int Preference { get; set; }
    public int Vaccine_FK { get; set; }
}

 class Vaccine
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string VaccineName { get; set; }
}
class PersonPrefs
{
    public int Person_FK { get; set; }
    public string Pref1 { get; set; }
    public string Pref2 { get; set; }
}

class NamedPersonPrefs
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Pref1 { get; set; }
    public string Pref2 { get; set; }
}
```

This is a self-contained C# program which should produce a result similar to what you're after. You will of course need to adjust the class definitions (and change the table names) to suit your needs.

I've used LINQ's fluent syntax but you can use the SQL-like version if you prefer.